# INSERT & UPDATE MySql table using PySpark DataFrames and JDBC

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, upsert

I'm trying to insert and update some data on MySql using PySpark SQL DataFrames and JDBC connection.

I've succeeded to insert new data using the SaveMode.Append. Is there a way to update the existing data and insert new data in MySql Table from PySpark SQL?

My code to insert is:

`myDataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(JDBCurl,mySqlTable,connectionProperties)`

If I change to SaveMode.Overwrite it deletes the full table and creates a new one, I'm looking for something like the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" available in MySql

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a view in `Mysql` as `create view <viewName> as select ...<tableName>`
2. Create trigger in mysql to update after insert using -

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER INSERT
    ON <viewName> FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- statements
    -- INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement
END$$
```

ref - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/

3. Write data to view `<viewName>` from spark